# Scala Convert java.sql.ResultSet to Json Object

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using Spark 2.3.1 and I've retrieved the resultSet from MySQL using JDBC Connection. resultSet is type of java.sql.ResultSet. so how to Convert ResultSet into JSON Object.

**I don't have to use Spark SQL**

Code for fetching resultSet is this

```
var connection:Connection = null
connection: java.sql.Connection = null

scala> Class.forName(driver)
res0: Class[_] = class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

scala> connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)
connection: java.sql.Connection = com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@79777da7

scala> val statement = connection.createStatement()
statement: java.sql.Statement = com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl@68360fb9

scala> val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name")
resultSet: java.sql.ResultSet = com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@4ebed2b3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get resultset meta and take columns count, then iterate:

```
val meta = resultSet.getMetaData
val colsCount = meta.getColumnCount
var colsMap: Map[Int, String] = Map.empty[Int, String]
// save col index and colName to a map, to compute later json with "key" and value
for (i <- 1 to colsCount) {
   colsMap +=  i -> meta.getColumnName(i)
}

while (resultSet.next()) {
     for (i <- 1 to colsCount) {
        val value = resultSet.getObject(i)
        // here you take colName from specific index and save it in a list of JsValues
        // as { "colsMap(i)" : "value" }
        // using spray-json or any other json library
     }
}
```

Edit: Based on my research I want to extend this answer.

So to Convert ResultSet to Json String I'm using JacksonMapper library, to import this library command would be like this

```
./bin/spark-shell --packages "com.lambdaworks:jacks_2.11:2.3.3" --driver-class-path path-of/mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar 
--jars path-of/mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar 
-i path-to/ScalaApp.scala
```

**Program snippet**

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

import scala.collection.mutable.Map
import com.lambdaworks.jacks._

val meta = query_resultSet.getMetaData
    
    // Get total column count from metadata
    val colsCount = meta.getColumnCount
    var colsMap: Map[Int, String] = Map.empty[Int, String]
    
    // Create ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Map(String, String)]]
    var final_array = ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]]]()
    
    // Fill colsMap from columnName
    for (i <- 1 to colsCount) {
        colsMap +=  i -> meta.getColumnName(i)
    }

    while (query_resultSet.next()) {
        var result_array = ArrayBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]]()
        for (i <- 1 to colsCount)
        {
            var temp_map = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
            val cols = colsMap(i)
            val value = query_resultSet.getObject(i)
            temp_map(s"$cols") = s"$value"
            result_array += temp_map
        }
        final_array += result_array
    }

    // for Array: use JacksMapper to convert ArrayBuffer[Map(String, String)] to [{"column1":"value1"},{"column2":"value2"}]
    
     val  json_string = JacksMapper.writeValueAsString(final_array)
```

**Here we are using Jackson Mapper Library to Convert Map values into Json String.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import value.{JsObj,JsArray}
val emp = JsObjSpec("name" -> getNameFromRS()),
                           "last_name" -> str(getNameFromRS()),
                           "profession" -> str(getProfFromRS()), 
                           "country" -> enum("US"),               
                           "languages" -> arrayOfStr((getLangFromRS()),
                           "age" -> getAgeFromRS(),,
                           * -> any 
                           )
```

Comment: Actually at run time I don't have knowledge about table schema, because query will fire on tables according to loop variable, so can you please elaborate your answer, because I'm new to scala.

Answer (score 0):

If using a third party library is an option here, you could use [jOOQ's JSON export functionality](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/exporting/exporting-json/) for this:

```java
DSLContext ctx = ...
String json = ctx.fetch(resultSet).formatJSON();
```

There are various JSON formatting options for different record and result layouts. The example above reads directly from your JDBC `ResultSet`, but you could, of course, also create and execute your query with jOOQ directly, or use the [native SQL/JSON support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/json-functions/). A lot of times, it's not necessary to write any middleware logic when you want to produce JSON from database results. [You could generate the JSON directly from within SQL](https://blog.jooq.org/stop-mapping-stuff-in-your-middleware-use-sqls-xml-or-json-operators-instead/).

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.